# How to set data attribute with jQuery on element that is not in DOM yet?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-data

How can I set the data-attribute with jQuery on an element that is not in the DOM yet?

Code:

```
   var panelHeading = $('<div/>', {class:'panel-heading', href:'#'+username+'PanelContent'});
   panelHeading.data('toggle', 'collapse').data('target',"#"+username+"PanelContent");
```

The data attributes don't appear when I append it to the document. The other attributes do appear.

Comment: Why not just set them in the initial declaration? `, data-toggle: "collapse"`

Comment: Note that `class` is a reserved keyword.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add data attributes when creating the element

```
var panelHeading = $('<div />', {
    'class'       : 'panel-heading', 
    href          : '#'+username+'PanelContent',
    'data-toggle' : 'collapse',
    'data-target' : '#'+username+'PanelContent'
});
```

using `data()` stores the data internally in jQuery, it does not create HTML attributes, so it works rather poorly with attributes for things like Bootstrap

Answer (score 4):

jQuery's `data()` method doesn't set HTML5 `data-` attributes, it actually stores high-level data in the DOM element. You can store complex objects and functions using `data()` that you can't using attributes.

If you really must set an attribute, use `attr('data-toggle','collapse')` and the like. But as mentioned in an earlier comment, why not just set it in the initial declaration?

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
var panelHeading = $('<div data-target="' + '#'
    + username + 'PanelContent' + '"/>');
```